# Charging for digital goods in Google Docs Addon (apps script) now that Wallet for digital goods is retired?

Tags: google-apps-script, android-pay

Any tips for charging for digital goods now that Google Wallet for digital goods is retired? https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573
Could we use the Chrome Web Store API? https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Romain Vialard [has monetized one of his add-ons using PayPal](https://web.archive.org/web/20201023012832/https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/ivestartedalittleexperiment), you could take a look at that.